# Replicate a system as is

Tags: package-management, custom-distributions

How do i repliacate a system as is.

i have installed ubuntu from the minimal iso...

i have kept it to minimum

now i m using UCK to customise a live cd

is there anyway i can replicate my installed system as is? 
i.e. install apps that i have install and remove apps that i have not installed/removed

i tried using synaptics and saving the marking full state way and when i read it when customizing, it doesnt remove the apps that i have removed it just reads installs more apps, it doesnt remove

Comment: Use Remastersys.

Comment: hate it, ISO size is larger in comparison to UCK

Comment: Uhmm, depends if you make a complete copy of the system as it is, then yes it's going to be huge.

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal window, `dpkg --get-selections` will list all the packages in your local database, with either "install" or "deinstall". That should let you duplicate your package selection. Have you considered what to do about configuration?

Comment: no not yet, havent tried that, which configuration ?

Comment: this gives only install packaged... what about the ones i wanna remove...
if by configuration u mean selecting themes, default apps and the login and desktop background yes i would love to change that...

i tried remaster sys but their iso is huge sized as compared to UCK plus i have the modified first boot screen in remaster sys